# Winform Column list

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, multiple-columns

I'm very new to programming so apologies if this is a very obvious question. Ive searched online but not found an answer that quite fits yet.

I am writing a programme that interprets bytes from an index within a filestream. Once they have been converted into human readable dates/strings/ints etc I wanted to use a Winform to display the results in columns. Currently I  using a listbox and just dispalying each entry seperated by columns but this feels lile a very clunky way of doing it.

Can someone please suggest how I might go about placing the results into a display that uses columns?

Comment: You *want* to display it in columns and you *have* it displayed in columns. What's the problem? You can also use a ListView, DataGrid or GridView but the principle is the same...

Comment: Sorry correction - my current set up is a listbox which just displays each entry of multiple fields in a row of strings. I want to seperate these by columns.

Comment: That's what a ListView is for. (Or _possibly_ a DataGridView)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to use a `ListView` than a `ListBox` in your case. Here's an example showing all words in a string in separate columns in a ListView:

Make sure following property is set to your ListView (here the Name is ColumnsListView):

```
ColumnsListView.View = View.Details;
```

This method takes a string, splits it by space and adds a column for each of the values:

```
private void SetListView(string input)
{
    var values = input.Split(' ');
    ColumnsListView.Columns.Add("Column1");
    var item = new ListViewItem(values[0]);

    for (var i = 1; i < values.Length; i++)
    {
        ColumnsListView.Columns.Add("Column" + (i+1));
        item.SubItems.Add(new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem { Text = values[i] });
    }

    ColumnsListView.Items.Add(item);
}
```

This can be done differently when using LinQ's `Skip()` method to add the item with subitems:

```
private void SetListView(string input)
{
    var values = input.Split(' ');

    for (var i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        ColumnsListView.Columns.Add("Column" + (i + 1));

    var item = new ListViewItem(values[0]);
    item.SubItems.AddRange(values.Skip(1).ToArray());
    ColumnsListView.Items.Add(item);
}
```

**Update:**

Here's an example in case you want to use a `DataGridView`:

```
private void SetDataGridView(string input)
{
    var values = input.Split(' ');

    for (var i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        ColumnsDataGridView.Columns.Add("Column" + (i + 1), "Column" + (i + 1));

    ColumnsDataGridView.Rows.Add(values);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll give it a go and see if that works for th data I have. Are different columns able to hold different types or do I have to convert to string first?

Comment: The value that is displayed is Always a string altough the containing item can be anything. Like a ListBoxItem can be an instance of a `Person` class and the first name of that person is displayed in the item.